# How to insert new line in rich textbox by pressing enter?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, richtextbox

In my vb net project, I have a form where I use the ENTER key as Tab to move between textbox controls in the forms KeyDown event.

```
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        Me.SelectNextControl(Me.ActiveControl, True, True, True, False)

        'remove beep sound
        e.SuppressKeyPress = True
    End If
```

Problem is, I need to work on a rich textbox which I'm saving to a notepad file, but can not insert new line by pressing enter because I'm using it as Tab.

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: Well, make a choice what Enter does in your app.  You could also use Ctrl-Enter for Enter.  The user is likely already confused, so why not...

Comment: `The user is likely already confused` can't agree more

Comment: Why not just use `Tab` as tab?

Comment: Well, it's just a customer request. I'm thinking other possible ways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are certain places in VS that the Enter key does something other than add a new line and Ctrl+Enter is used to add a new line.  To detect Ctrl+Enter in a keyboard event:

```
If e.KeyData = (Keys.Control Or Keys.Enter) Then
```

It may seem like that should be `And` rather than `Or` but it is a bitwise operation so `Or` is correct.